# Zend _redirect error: prepends base url twice

Tags: zend-framework, redirect

**I'm experiencing irregular behavior** using the Zend controller `_redirect` method.

My copy of the application is yielded via a symlink in my `DocumentRoot`. Also my default router is customized to respond to this pattern:

`http://localhost/<appSymLink>/<param_A>/<controller>/<action>/`

From a controller, I construct a URL like so:

`$url = $this->_helper->url('action', 'controller', $param_A = 'valueA');`

*If I access the url:*

`http://localhost/<appSymLink>/<param_A>/<controller>/<action>/`

This variable contains the following string:

`/<appSymLink>/<param_A>/<controller>/<action>/`

*And when I call*

`$this->_redirect($url);`

The user is explicitly redirected to this path, *with redundant base paths*.

`/<appSymLink>/<appSymLink>/<param_A>/<controller>/<action>/`

Zend seems to be prepending the base path twice.

My co-worker's copy of the application lives in his `DocumentRoot`, and he is not experiencing this problem.

*Defining an empty base path* inside the action, just before the operation, works like so:

`$this->getRequest()->setBaseUrl('');`

This is not a feasible solution obviously. On the other hand, doing this within a controller plugin at `routeShutdown` eliminates both occurrences of the application directory.

*Does anyone have advice* for a solution to this problem, or any tips for looking fourther into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If redirecting with a URL generated from the `Url` helper, you need to inform the redirector that it is already prefixed with the base URL.

Simply use the following

```
return $this->redirect($url, array('prependBase' => false));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try and set the `prependBase` option to `FALSE`:
`$this->_redirect($url, array('prependBase' => FALSE);`

> Excerpt from ZF reference:
>   **_redirect($url, array $options = array()):** redirect to another location. This method takes a URL and an optional set of options. By
>   default, it performs an HTTP 302 redirect.
>
> The options may include one or more of the following:
>
> **exit:** whether or not to exit immediately. If requested, it will
>   cleanly close any open sessions and perform the redirect.
>
> You may set this option globally within the controller using the
>   setRedirectExit() accessor.
>
> **prependBase:** whether or not to prepend the base URL registered with
>   the request object to the URL provided.
>
> You may set this option globally within the controller using the
>   setRedirectPrependBase() accessor.
>
> **code:** what HTTP code to utilize in the redirect. By default, an HTTP
>   302 is utilized; any code between 301 and 306 may be used.
>
> You may set this option globally within the controller using the
>   setRedirectCode() accessor.

if this dosen't work may I suggest the action helper 'Redirector'
commonly used:
 `$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = array())`
[Action Helper Redirector](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector)